# The derivative of f(x) = 1/x confuses me

Tags: limits, derivatives

$f(x) = \frac1x $

$  \frac{d}{dx} f(x) = \frac{-1}{x^2}$

$nx^{n-1}$

However, using the formal definition of a derivative

$\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h}$

We get:

$ \frac{\frac{1}{x+h} - \frac{1}{x}}{h}$

$ \frac{\frac{x}{(x+h)(x)} - \frac{x+h}{x(x+h)}}{h}$

$\frac{-h}{h(x+h)(x)}$

$ \frac{-1}{(x+h)(x)}$

$\frac{-1}{x^2+xh}$

Now, I was always taught to ignore $h^2$ terms but the $xh$ here seems like it shouldn't be ignored. But it is, and I'm confused why.

Comment: You working is correct, but you were taught poorly.  $\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h}$ means, "The limit of $\frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h}$ as $h\to 0$ (in terms of $x$)." Which in this case you correctly deduce is the same as, $\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{-1}{x^2+xh}.$ So what does the expression $\frac{-1}{x^2+xh}$ "tend to" (in terms of $x$) as  $h\to 0$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track. It's not that we "ignore" the $xh$ or $h^2$ term, it's that after you've done all the algebraic manipulations, you have to remember to take the limit. So rewriting (and assuming $x\neq 0$): $$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{-1}{x^2+xh}=\frac{-1}{x^2}$$

Comment: Thanks, i didn't compute the limit after the i got $\frac{-1}{x^2+xh}$ earlier, but I did it now, and I got the correct answer